# How do I create a user with limited privileges?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create an SSH user which can access only certain directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/299036/can-i-create-an-ssh-user-which-can-access-only-certain-directory)

I have a CentOS 5.7 installation which I access via SSH. I currently have a root user with which I access the server and can do whatever I like.

I would like to create another user which is only allowed to see what is under `/home` and maybe also limit the commands that he is allowed to execute.

To put my request in a better context: I want to ceate a user which can only run SVN commands in `/home`.

Comment: For the other part, it's hard to define what "SVN" commands are, or what you really don't want the user to do. If they're `chroot`ed, they have very little privileges anyway.

Comment: Alsp, see [Server Fault for more on this topic](http://serverfault.com/search?q=limit+ssh+user+to+home): [CopSSH SFTP — limit users access to their home directory only](http://serverfault.com/questions/132331/copssh-sftp-limit-users-access-to-their-home-directory-only) [Restrict access to SSH for one specific user](http://serverfault.com/questions/216502/restrict-access-to-ssh-for-one-specific-user)