# Make /var/www accessible only for root and web server

Tags: linux, permissions, webserver

I'm a web developer. I'm allowing SSH access to my machine for a couple of people.

I want to make sure that they can't access my files in `/var/www/`.

So is it possible to make these files readable only to the web server and give read/write access to the root user?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the Apache user is called `www-data`. If you want the files in `/var/www/` to become readable only by this user, you need to give it ownership:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/
```

Now you want `www-data` to be the only user that can actually read/write those:

```
sudo chmod -R 700 /var/www/
```

Note that `root` always has read/write access to any file, regardless of the permissions. Whether this setup is a good idea or not – well, I'd rather chroot these SSH users to their home folders. See [Can I create an SSH user which can access only certain directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/299036/can-i-create-an-ssh-user-which-can-access-only-certain-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your web server's user (usually www-data):

```
chown www-data /var/www
chmod -R 700 /var/www
```

This will set the www-data user the owner of your /var/www directory and will allow accessing the directory only to the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make root or another user the owner of your web content.  This will prevent the web server from overwriting content if someone gains access via a script or other entry point.  Replace `root` in these commands with whatever user you want to own the content.

```
chown -R root:www-data /var/www
chmod 2750 /var/www
```

To allow the `user` (other than root) to maintain the content you will need to add the user to the www-data group.

```
adduser user www-data
```

Some web applications may have some directories where they write dynamic content.  To allow access either change the owner to www-data or allow group write.